# Error: “The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts”

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

When I try to get all users with department name they belong, Using ASP.Net MVC I keep getting this error in this line:

```
DepartmentName = db.Departments.Where(d => d.DepartmentId == u.DepartmentId).Select(n =>n.DepartmentName).ToString()
```

From what I searched in google, I think I have to perform two queries but I don't know how to do it.
This is my ViewModel

```
public class UserListViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    }
```

And Action

```
public ActionResult Users()
        {

            List<UserListViewModel> model = new List<UserListViewModel>();

            model = UserManager.Users.Select(u => new UserListViewModel
            {

                Id = u.Id,
                FirstName = u.FirstName,
                LastName = u.LastName,
                Email = u.Email,

               DepartmentName = db.Departments.Where(d => d.DepartmentId == u.DepartmentId).Select(n =>n.DepartmentName).ToString()

            }).ToList();
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `UserManager` and `db` are two different contexts. Try moving the `DepartmentName` selection out of your query to get the user - just get it after you have the user's id.

Comment: @Dido Thank you for responsing but how can I fetch Users and Departments separatly, can you please show me? I tried Before Like this DepartmentName = db.Departments.Where(d => d.DepartmentId == ?????).Select(n =>n.DepartmentName).ToString() , But d => d.DepartmentId  with what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linq to entities query gets translated in to sql and it gets executed in the sql server, the above code is using two different context instances in single query i.e. `UserManager` and `db` and the framework does not allow having two different database contexts in a single query.

you can fetch `Users` and `Departments` separately in memory and then organize them in one collection or you would need to use same context to query the data (using `db` for both `Users` and `Departments`) and then you can fetch both results in single request to database server.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for responsing but how can I fetch Users and Departments separatly, can you please show me? I tried Before Like this DepartmentName = db.Departments.Where(d => d.DepartmentId == ?????).Select(n =>n.DepartmentName).ToString() , But d => d.DepartmentId  with what?

Comment: second approach is more suitable in your use case using same context class will allow you to fetch using the query you currently have, i mean use `db` object for both `Users` and `Departments`

Comment: Thank you I realy don't know why I used context instead of db. Now it's working with db.

Comment: `db` is actually object of `DbContext` class, what's wrong was using different context classes in same query. Glad to help btw.